# MS SQL after upgrade from 2014 to 2016 JOIN takes longer

Tags: sql-server

I have an sql code that outer join 4 tables from 2 database. The tables have 30000 rows each. In sql 2014 the query took 0s. After an upgrade to sql 2016 i have a deterioration in every JOIN query i use, the query in question needs 1m30s to complete. The server isn't used when i made the tests. How can i search what is wrong? I tried running sql profiler and adding resources to the machine (its a virtual machine having a whole ibm x3650 to itself).

Answer (score 0):

OK i got it, i had to rebuild the statistics with `EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1='UPDATE STATISTICS ? WITH FULLSCAN'`

Answer (score 0):

After update all the statistics, compare the plan in the two versions.

You can use query story to monitor and force some plan.